# store rendered component in variable

Tags: reactjs

This is my first project in ReactJs.
I want to store the output from for loop in a variable and I will render the stored variable, instead of call this loop because the loop size is more then 1000 row .
I want to take this step to improve performance when the user back to this page.

```
class Main extends Component {
    static contextType = MyContext

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            loading: true,
            isError: false
        };
        this.location = props.location
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.context.sectionData.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                data: this.context.sectionData,
                loading: false,
                isError: false
            })
        } else {
            fetch("./api/getSections.php")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    this.context.setSectionData(result);
                    this.setState({
                        data: result,
                        loading: false,
                        isError: false
                    })
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.setState({
                        isError: true
                    })
                })
        }

    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (this.state.data.length > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isError) {
            return (
                <h2>Error internet</h2>
            )
        } else if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <Loading />
            )
        } else {
            return (
                this.state.data.map((sectionItem, idx) => {
                    if (sectionItem.list.length > 0) {
                        return MainSection(sectionItem, idx); // <--- I want to store the output from this in a variable and i will render the stored variable, instead of call this loop because the loop size is more then 1000 row
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    }

}
```

MainSection :

```
function MainSection(data, idx) {

    return (
        <section className="noBox" key={idx}>
            <div className="headlineHolder">
                <div className="headName">
                    <img src={data.cat_img} alt="#" />
                    <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                </div>
                <a href="#" className="button">Show all</a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                {data.list.map((item, idx) => (
                    <li key={idx} >
                        <Link to={{ pathname: `/show/${item.id}`, data: item }} >
                            <div className="gameBox">
                                <div className="gameImg">
                                    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.img})` }} alt={item.name} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="gameInfo">
                                    <div className="name">
                                        {item.name}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="players">
                                        {item.plays} plays
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="ratings">
                                <div className="empty-stars"></div>
                                <div className="full-stars" style={{ width: 25 }}> </div>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </section >
    );
}

export default MainSection
```

If that is not possible is there a way to improve performance to do this procedure, for example Recyclerview on Android it display only part of views when user do scroll.

Comment: What does your `MainSection` function look like?

Comment: @codemonkey MainSection  is a component

Comment: I got that part, but we do need to see it to help you.

Comment: @codemonkey I update the question and  added the MainSection

Comment: data.list.map it's normal practice in React use map in return (or render) ofcourse you can save component in variable, but I don't think that it improves performance. any way just do this somewhere: const children = data.list.map... and you'll get what you want

Comment: @DaniilLoban I want to avoid using a loop every time the main component is called , because This will impair performance if the array size is as large as 1000 row or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good when using data that `doesn't change`. But if they don't change, then React doesn't need to `restart the loop`, provided that `useMemo` is used, this can be guaranteed. React is quite optimal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
      const MyList = ({ children }) => (<ul>{children}</ul>)
      const MyItem = ({item}) => (<li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>)

      const data = [
        {id: 1, text: 'a'},
        {id: 2, text: 'b'},
        {id: 3, text: 'c'},
        {id: 4, text: 'd'}]
      
      // here we sotore items in variable but better use useMemo hook
      const savedItems = data.map(e => (
        <MyItem key={e.id} item={e}/>
      ))

      const App = () => (<MyList>{savedItems}</MyList>)

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```